# Load files with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to load several data files (file1.xml, file2.xml, file3.xml,..) with

```
jQuery.getJSON
```

My objective is to load data in an application which is based on JQuery+HTML5.

Comment: What is your requirement .. it is not understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in the same domain as the javascript code executing the AJAX request, you can do it by a simple jQuery get request:

```
$.get("/url-to-source",function(response){
   //do what ever you want to do with response
});
```

If the data resides in a different domain than your javascript code, you should use jsonp, see examples:

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/